# What is standard .NET Core interface for deleting file?

Tags: c#, .net-core

As far as I can see, there are three [file providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in the .NET Core. now I want to delete a file, but there is no `delete` method in the [IFileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.ifileinfo?view=aspnetcore-2.1) interface.

What is the standard interface in the .**NET Core** to manipulate files? I want to delete or write a file etc.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=netframework-4.7.2  `File.Delete(path)` is available in .Net Core

Comment: Those providers are for ASP.Net to access file-system-like systems, not for general file IO.

Comment: You should explain what you really want. You mentioned in another comment that you want to access S3. Why not use the AWS SDK? Why do you want to create *another* abstration? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I should use IFileInfo because I can't directly inject AWS SDK in the ConfigureServices method of the ASP.NET Core

Comment: Cloud storage is *very* different from local file systems. There are no folders, the file prefix can affect performance (specifics varies by provider), paging can be unavoidable, versioning is provided out of the box.

Comment: @MRP add that to the question itself. Besides, why do you think you *can't* inject anything you want in ConfigureServices? It's just code. The AWS SDK already provided some mechanisms and a couple of days ago it released another version, with additional configuration providers

Answer (score 5):

It's worth differentiating between ASP.NET Core and .NET Core. You linked to ASP.NET Core documentation for file providers, which are used to *read* files which might be virtual files within an assembly etc.

For plain file system access, use [`System.IO.File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netcore-2.2) as you do in desktop .NET. That's been part of .NET Core since version 1. It allows files to be created, appended, read, deleted etc.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I'm looking for ASP.NET Core. but I'm looking for an interface like IFileInfo. cos I'm going to write my own delete implementation.

Comment: The reason behind this is that I'm trying to implement Amazon S3 file provider. actually, I can't use System.IO.File

Comment: @MRP: At this point it's very unclear what you're trying to achieve. I'd suggest creating a new question with much more context. There simply isn't a general purpose file system interface in either .NET Core or ASP.NET Core as far as I'm aware. You could always create your own, potentially...

Comment: @MRP why do you need to add another abstraction? IFileInfo is only for reading. The AWS SDK for .NET Core provides its own abstractions and API. Cloud storage is *very* different from local file systems. There are no directories for example

Comment: Thanks for your help, so I will deal with this issue with a custom extension method.